# Add hyphen in between letters and hyphen

Tags: excel

I have a list of sample names:

TW1

UD1

SS1

S17

SS23

UD12

I wish to add a hyphen in between the letters and the numbers as such:

TW-1

UD-1

SS-1

S-17

SS-23

UD-12

UD786

I tried this:

=MID(A1,1,COUNT(1*MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},1)))&"-"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,1,COUNT(1*MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},1))),"")

The results were not consistent. It gives the following results:

T-W1

U-D1

S-1

S1-7

SS-23

UD-12

How may I achieve the desired output?

Comment: not the solution but if you are doing only once then can easily achieved using sublime text editor multicursor - ctrl+A, alt+ctrl+L press home key and twi right arrow key

Answer (score 0):

=LEFT(A1,2-ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,2,1)))&"-"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(2-ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,2,1))))

Is another option.  Trick in this is to convert your number as a string to a number before testing if its a number.  Instead of -- you could have done 1* or 0+.

This solution only works as your sample data was 1 or 2 characters before the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter than @Forward Ed's A:

```
=REPLACE(A1,2+(CODE(MID(A1,2,1))>64),,"-")
```